# Installing OpenGL for Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, installation

I just have installed Qt 4 on windows 7. I am now in a bit of a confusion
How do I get to install OpenGL so that it works with QT? Is there an installer for OpenGL?
Qt docs. say it has support for OpenGL, but when I include QTOpenGL and build, the compiler issues an error of  "No such file or directory"

Thanks for the reply in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What tool chain are you using? (Visual Studio, Qt Creator/g++) You need to specify somewhere in your project settings that you want to use the QtOpenGL module. This will result in a line in your .pro file similar to this:

```
QT = core gui opengl
```

This causes qmake to add the proper include path when invoking the compiler (I believe).

Comment: I am using QT Creator and added the line QT += opengl to the .pro file
THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you followed [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtopengl.html#details) to the letter? You need to include `<QtOpenGL>` and set the `QT += opengl` option in your pro file.

Answer (score 2):

added the line QT += opengl to the .pro file